# Bash script, redirect output to another directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have an environment variable containing the name of a directory. I am trying to redirect output from an echo command to a text file in a different directory.

For example

```
DIR="NewDirectory"
mkdir $DIR
echo "Testing" >> "$DIR\file.txt"
```

Results in a file named NewDirectory\file.txt in the working directory of the script...what exactly am I missing here? The directory is created without issue, so I am not sure what is going on here.

Comment: 2 changes `mkdir -p newdir` and `echo "testing" ${DIR}/file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change `\` into `/`:

```
DIR="NewDirectory"
mkdir -p $DIR
echo "Testing" >> "$DIR/file.txt"
```

Changed `mkdir -p` as suggested by @Jord, because `-p` means: no error if existing, make parent directories as needed

Answer (score 1):

In [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) (or [unix](/questions/tagged/unix) for that matter), the directory separator is a slash (`/`), not a backslash (`\`):

```
DIR="NewDirectory"
mkdir $DIR
echo "Testing" >> "$DIR/file.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
echo "Testing" >> "$DIR\file.txt"
```

should read

```
echo "Testing" >> "$DIR/file.txt"
```

as `/` is the separator in paths in Linux.